# List dates of specific month and exclude Friday and Saturday

Tags: excel

I could list the dates of a specific month based on the date in cell A1 using the following formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(DAY(ROW(1:30))&"-"&MONTH($A$1)&"-"&YEAR($A$1)),""))
```

Is it possible using formulas to list the dates but to exclude Friday and Saturday from the list generated?

Comment: have a look at the `Workday()` formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WORKDAY.INTL which allows the exclusion of weekdays:

```
=LET(dy,WORKDAY.INTL(A1-1,SEQUENCE(31),"0000110"),IF(dy>EOMONTH(A1,0),"",dy))
```

[image]

If you want it horizontal:

```
=LET(dy,WORKDAY.INTL(A1-1,SEQUENCE(,31),"0000110"),IF(dy>EOMONTH(A1,0),"",dy))
```

---

Without the dynamic array formula, put this in the first column and drag over:

```
=IF(WORKDAY.INTL(A1-1,COLUMN(A1),"0000110")>EOMONTH(A1,0),"",WORKDAY.INTL(A1-1,COLUMN(A1),"0000110"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The month started with the day 2 while 1 should be included as Wednesday for the date 1 sept 2021

Comment: @YasserKhalil see edit.  I forgot to subtract 1 at the start.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does the number "0000110" refer to? is it for two days Friday and Saturday? How can I know the reference for other days if I need to make any changes

Comment: `0` means use that day. `1` means skip that day.  The first digit is `Monday`.  See [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much.